# Refactoring business logic with if and severals else if

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have method that returns list of employee positions `List<string> listPositions`. If method returns only one string basic logic would be something like this:

```
if (listPositions.Contains("Admin"))
{
   // business logic 1,for example Console.WriteLine("I'm Admin");
}
else if (listPositions.Contains("OfficeDirector"))
{
  //business logic 2
}
else if (listPositions.Contains("Regular") || listPositions.Contains("HumanResource"))
{
  //business logic 3
}
```

Now, method can return more than one string, so employee can be Admin and Office Director for example.Now I need to combine implementation in first `if` and first `else if` and I don't want to get lost inside several if-statements, so I'm asking you if there is more elegant solution to this problem .
Thank you.

Comment: First things first, switch the data structure to a `HashSet` instead of a `List`.

Answer (score 2):

You can define `Dictionary<string, Action>` or `Dictionary<string, Func>` like

```
Dictionary<string, Action> actions = new Dictionary<string, Action>
{
  { "Admin", new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("I'm Admin")) },
  { "OfficeDirector", new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("I'm OfficeDirector")) },
  { "Regular", new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("I'm Regular or HumanResource")) },
  { "HumanResource", new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("I'm Regular or HumanResource")) },
};
```

and then simply call the logic:

```
foreach(var position in listPositions) {
  if (actions.ContainsKey(position)) {
    actions[position]();
  }
}
```

Edit:
Or use as a key `Predicate<string>`, bit more complicated example:

```
static Dictionary<Predicate<string>, Action> PredicatedActions = new Dictionary<Predicate<string>, Action>()
{
  { p => p == "Admin", new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("I'm Admin")) },
  { p => p == "OfficeDirector", new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("I'm OfficeDirector")) },
  { p => p == "HumanResource" || p == "Regular", new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("I'm Regular or HumanResource")) }
};
```

then just call applicable actions:

```
var actionToExecute = listPositions.SelectMany(
  position => PredicatedActions.Keys.Where(condition => condition(position)).Select(key => PredicatedActions[key])
).Distinct();

actionToExecute.ToList().ForEach(action => action());
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use here is a [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). The seminal text on this is the [Gang Of Four](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Design-patterns-elements-reusable-object-oriented/dp/0201633612) book by Gamma et. al. If you are new to design patterns, [Head First Design Patterns](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Head-First-Design-Patterns-Freeman/dp/0596007124) may be more accessible. Plenty of websites and other resources discuss the pattern. I highly recommend you check it out and the other design patterns discussed in these resources.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/06tc147t.aspx) statement, I find them a lot easier to read.

Or, rather than using if / else, if / else, just have a bunch of if statements in a row. These can then catch the valid positions:

```
if (listPositions.Contains("Admin"))
{
   // Concatenate some string or add to a list for final checking
}
if (listPositions.Contains("OfficeDirector"))
{
  // Concatenate some string or add to a list for final checking
}
if (listPositions.Contains("Regular") || listPositions.Contains("HumanResource"))
{
  // Concatenate some string or add to a list for final checking
}
```

Then have some check at the end for which positions the person holds, and apply all the relevant business logic.